# How to implement an epoch-dependent parameter inside a neural network in Pytorch?

Tags: pytorch

For example, let's say I want to use Softmax with temperature after a layer and I also want to decrease the temperature after 5 epochs.

```
for epoch in range(EPOCHS):
running_loss = 0.0
for i, data in enumerate(trainloader, 0):
    inputs, labels = data[0].to(torch_device), data[1].to(torch_device)
    optimizer.zero_grad()
    outputs = my_model(inputs)
    loss = criterion(outputs, labels)
    loss.backward()
    optimizer.step()
    my_model.adjust_softmax_temperature(epoch)
    # ...
```

How should I implement the adjust_softmax_temperature method in order to make my code to work?

Comment: You could say `if epoch % 5 == 0: my_model.adjust_softmax_temperature(epoch)` That would adjust the temperature every five epochs

Comment: @DwightFoster - agree, but how do I implement adjust_softmax_temperature? Because, as far as I know, the model is loaded BEFORE thre training, and the forward step passes data through the already-defined model. Am I missing something here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> as far as I know, the model is loaded BEFORE thre training, and the forward step passes data through the already-defined model. Am I missing something here?

You can mutate the state of your model even *after* it has been defined. In this case, we're interested in changing a property of `my_model` during training.

Here is a broad overview of how you could implement this.

First, expose a function to update the model's temperature based on the provided epoch number:

```
class MyModel(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, t0):
        self.t = t0
    
    def forward(self, x):
        # compute forward pass using self.t
        pass

    def adjust_softmax_temperature(self, epoch):
        if epoch % 5:
            self.t /= 10 # update policy of temperature
```

Then, after having defined your model, you can call the update function at the end of each epoch: it will decide based on `epoch` wether to update `self.t` or not.

```
my_model = MyModel(t0=100)

for epoch in range(EPOCHS):
    for i, data in enumerate(trainloader, 0):
        # train iteration
    my_model.adjust_softmax_temperature(epoch)
```

Comment: Thanks, I guess that, following the same principles it is possible to adjust, while training the data augmentation regime (for example if I want to apply image augmentation with a higher probability after a certain epoch)

Comment: Yes, that could be achieve fairly easily if you are using a custom `torch.utils.data.Dataset`.